# `contentOffset` does not execute when rect Y value of glyph is significantly distant from preceding rect

Tags: swift, contentoffset

Anyone experience an issue with `contentOffset` when using it to scroll to a `rect` of a string in a `UITextView` but the view does not scroll at all? It is as if `contentOffset` does not know what to do with the `rect` passed to it. This error ocurrs **only** when there is significant vertical distance between two `rect` values relative to the `contentsize.height` of the `UITextView`. Otherwise, `contentOffset` works fine: it will scroll the view to each `rect` value passed to `contentOffset`. I am using `layoutManager` to get the `rect` of the glyph to pass into `contentOffset`.

The problem appears to be corrected if I first manually scroll to the bottom of the view and then execute `contentoffset`.  I am not sure why first scrolling to the bottom of the `UITextView` corrects the error.

My original post did not include the code which is executed when pressing button.  The function receives one NSRange at a time.  The NSRange values are stored in an array and the button increments to each NSRange value and converts into a `rect`.

```
 // called when button pressed.  
 func matchProcessing(matchRange:NSRange, InTextView textView:UITextView){

 // unhide the rounded rectangle view that will circle matched text
 self.detailText.viewWithTag(1)?.isHidden = false

//get rect of NSRange of matched text 
let matchTxtRect = textView.layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: matchRange, in: textView.textContainer)

 //animation of scroll and rounded rectangle view

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations:

    {

        textView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: matchTxt.origin.y)

      // get rect of                      
        let nextDestination = self.frameOfTextInRange(range: self.arrayOfMatches[self.matchIndex], inTextView: textView)

        //this does not work either: let nextDestination = textView.layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: self.arrayOfMatches[self.matchIndex], in: textView.textContainer)

        let destination = textView.viewWithTag(1)?.convert(textView.viewWithTag(1)!.center, from: textView.viewWithTag(1)?.superview)

         textView.viewWithTag(1)?.move(to: (destination?.applying(
                CGAffineTransform(translationX: nextDestination.origin.x, y: nextDestination.origin.y)))!,
                              duration: 0.8,
                              options: .curveEaseInOut)

          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay:0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.detailText.viewWithTag(1)?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)

        })

        }, completion: nil )
```

}

Comment: Glyph hasn’t been rendered in far away case so the text passed is nonsense? Might explain why scrolling to bottom fixes the issue.

Comment: Warren - added the code to my question.  Maybe you are correct since the function looks at one `rect` at a time.  Not sure how to fix this issue.